# symmetricDS with greenplum

Tags: postgresql, greenplum, symmetricds

I want to replicate data from Postgres to Greenplum. But encountered some problems.
I used the https://github.com/kevinmtrowbridge/greenplumdb_singlenode_docker
and SymmetricDS community version.

I have added `custom_variable_classes = 'symmetric'` into greenplum config. But the problem is still not fixed.

```
[sunclient-003] - RegistrationService - Could not register. Sleeping before attempting again.
[sunclient-003] - RegistrationService - Sleeping for 24000ms
[sunclient-003] - RegistrationService - This node is unregistered. It will attempt to register using the registration.url
[sunclient-003] - DataLoaderService - Using registration URL of http://172.25.4.121:8080/sync/sunserver-000/registration?nodeGroupId=sunclient&externalId=003&syncURL=http%3A%2F%2F172.25.2.187%3A9090%2Fsync%2Fsunclient-003&schemaVersion=%3F&databaseType=PostgreSQL&databaseVersion=8.2&symmetricVersion=3.8.4&hostName=localhost.localdomain&ipAddress=172.25.2.187
[sunclient-003] - DataLoaderService - Failed to load batch 000--9999
org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "symmetric" (seg0 b99744612d0b:40000 pid=7357)
at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.translate(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:283)
at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.translate(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:274)
at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTransaction.executeCallback(JdbcSqlTransaction.java:381)
at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTransaction.prepareAndExecute(JdbcSqlTransaction.java:347)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.db.postgresql.PostgreSqlSymmetricDialect.disableSyncTriggers(PostgreSqlSymmetricDialect.java:198)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService$ManageIncomingBatchListener.afterBatchStarted(DataLoaderService.java:1013)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.DataProcessor.process(DataProcessor.java:107)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService$LoadIntoDatabaseOnArrivalListener$1.call(DataLoaderService.java:925)
at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataLoaderService$LoadIntoDatabaseOnArrivalListener$1.call(DataLoaderService.java:911)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "symmetric" (seg0 b99744612d0b:40000 pid=7357)
at org.postgresql.core.v2.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorMessage(QueryExecutorImpl.java:574)
at org.postgresql.core.v2.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:497)
at org.postgresql.core.v2.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:364)
at org.postgresql.core.v2.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:258)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:616)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:466)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:459)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTransaction$6.execute(JdbcSqlTransaction.java:357)
at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTransaction$6.execute(JdbcSqlTransaction.java:347)
at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTransaction.executeCallback(JdbcSqlTransaction.java:379)
... 10 more
```

Comment: `syntax error at or near "symmetric"` - that's the problem. Some part of your system is creating an invalid SQL statement. You need to find out what the complete statement is that fails and how it is generated

Comment: Seems like there's a problem in the side of synchronization at postgres side: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "symmetric" (seg0 b99744612d0b:40000 pid=7357)

Comment: I noticed the error. But I still have no idea what happened. I succeeded when I replicated data from postgres(source server)to postgres(target server). But when I changed the target DB from postgres to greenplum. It failed.